# How to make sequential filters with NSFetchedResultsController 

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I want to make sequential filters using NSFetchedResultsController. The goal is to display the more relevant results first.

For example : 
Entity person: name - country

1) The persons where the name contains by the search string.
2) The persons where the country contains the search string.

By sequential, I mean that I want to have first the search results 1) and then 2).

I don't know the right way to do that because you init NSFetchedResultsController with 1 NSFetchRequest. But here, I need 2 NSFetchRequest. The other problem using 2 requests is that I could generate duplicate items with the second request.

Is it possible to deal with that using NSFetchedResultsController ?

Thanks

Here is an example :

- record 1 :
  name : Peter
  country : Mauritius
- record 2 :
  name : Marc
  country : Mauritania
- record 3 :
  name : Maureen
  country : Belgium

If the user types "ma" in the searchbar:

I want to display first the name results and then the country results.

So here, the results would be in this order :

1. Marc ("MA"rc)
2. Maureen ("MA"ureen)
3. Peter ("MA"uritius)

Answer (score 1):

Two different things going on here:  filtering and sorting.

you can do sorting by calling `setSortDescriptors` on your NSFetchRequest.  It take an array of sort descriptors and each one would correspond to name or country or whatever.

filtering is done by predicates.  Use `setPredicate:` on your NSFetchRequest.  You only get one predicate, but it can have multiple criteria using and and or.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it's not really my question. What I want to do is sequential requests. I edited my question with an example to be more relevant.